# How to install nepali unicode traditional in ubuntu18.04

Tags: unicode, ubuntu-18.04

How do i add nepali unicode traditional in ubuntu system, i tried this one

https://askubuntu.com/questions/965671/how-to-install-nepali-unicode-traditional-font-in-ubuntu-16-4

which didnot work for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, follow every step

http://nepalitankan.blogspot.com/2013/10/ne-trad-ttf-for-linux.html